# How does the Item Drop System work in DoTA2 as of the Oracle Update

Tags: dota-2

I have been almost always getting no items when I play ranked matches. I checked the wiki and there isn't any helpful information about how the drop system works. Can someone explain why I'm not getting any drops?

Thanks,
~Colossal

Comment: Should be the same as before: The longer a single match goes on for, the more chances to get a drop, and this stacks with the Nemesis drops. **Just wondering: How long do your games last; what's their duration?**

Comment: The drop system was massively overhauled 2 (?) patches ago removing a load of common and uncommon items and adding in full sets as well as more "high value" items. To compensate, they made the drop system drop far more rarely than it used to.  I've played probably a couple of dozen games since it changed and have only seen a couple of drops in that time (both times being full sets)

Comment: @aytimothy, my games typically last anywhere from 45-75 minutes. Also, thanks for the help.

Comment: Wait... @franglais - You mean drops now drop whole sets as opposed to items?

Comment: I'm guessing that drops have gotten rarer (but the chances still scale the same; longer game = more chance). But I could be completely wrong.

Comment: @aytimothy Yeah, they've changed it so that's now the way.  Here's the blog post about it - http://www.dota2.com/news/updates/14840/

Comment: @aytimothy Also, it's now nothing to do with the length of any one game, just the length of time playing the game in total (I'm assuming not just idling in menu)

Comment: It's the length of the match @franglais. That's what I meant by a 'game'. A round; match of DoTA 2.

Answer (score 2):

OK, so we don't know the *actual* reason as that would be drifting into the whole game dev areas which is off topic.

The drop system was [changed on October 30th](http://www.dota2.com/news/updates/14840/) so that instead of being match-time based to game-time based. They also changed it so that instead of getting fairly frequent, common and uncommon item drops, you'd now get infrequent set and high level item drops.

This patch also removed getting a guaranteed drop when you levelled up as well.